# How to get text out of a ListView or similar control using UI Automation?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ui-automation

I am trying to scrape a ListView like control from an external application.  Now I am using `System.Windows.Automation`. With AutoIt v3 I've extracted the following information about the exact control I want to scrape text from:

```
>>>> Control <<<<
Class:  WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.34f5582_r6_ad1
Instance:   20
ClassnameNN:    WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.34f5582_r6_ad120
Name:   
Advanced (Class):   [CLASS:WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.34f5582_r6_ad1; INSTANCE:20]
ID: 1510520
Text:   
Position:   182, 164
Size:   1411, 639
ControlClick Coords:    300, 202
Style:  0x56010000
ExStyle:    0x00000000
Handle: 0x0000000000170C78
```

Now, I have noticed `ID = 1510520` and by using it I would be able to get the control

```
AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(1510520);
```

The control looks like a ListView or similar to that, but I can't do anything else with it.

[image: LisrView like control]

How I can now get the content of this control?

UPDATE:
Thanks to Jimi's recommendation inspect.exe from Windows 10 SDK worked the best! I was able to drill down to DataGridView.

[image]

Comment: It's a DataGridView. The Rows have a automation role or row (`0x1C`). But those are just containers. You have to get the Child elements of each row and inspect their ControlType property (the first element will probably have a `header` role, the others `edit`, `checkbox` etc.)

Comment: You may find using the [Accessibility Insights for Windows](https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/en/windows/overview/) application useful for determining the exposed automation patterns. If the subject control is a DatagridView, it will expose the [TablePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.tablepattern?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: @TnTinMn, thanks, but the Accessibility Insights for Windows is not showing anything for the app in question. Is there any other similar app that can do the same thing?

Comment: @Jimi do you have any code that I can look at for this?

Comment: "Accessibility Insights for Windows is not showing anything for the app"-I know this app is not the most intuitive (did you watch the [intro video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIu9ONdMGGg&feature=youtu.be)?), but it should have shown something.  You could also try the older [Accessibility tools - Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) program.  It is part of the Windows SDK.

Comment: I can, I think. Do you know how to get the Handle of the Window that owns that DataGridView? Programmatically, I mean, not using a tool. What detail do you use to find it (Title, Process ID, specific content etc.). Anyway, I'll post some standard UIAutomation (`System.Windows.Automation`) methods that I hope can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you can find the Window that contains the DataGridView from which to extract the data. The `GeDataGridViewDataTable()` method expects the Handle of that Window.

Let's break down these methods:

To get the AutomationElement of a Window of interest when its handle is already known, we could just use `window =` [`AutomationElement.FromHandle([Window Handle])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.fromhandle).

▶ Here I'm using an [AndCodition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.andcondition.-ctor) because you may have ProcessID and Window Title, so instead of filtering using `AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty` and `AutomationElement.NativeWindowHandleProperty`, you could use the `AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty` and `AutomationElement.NameProperty` as the conditions.

If the Window is found, the first child elements in the **`TreeScope.SubTree`** scope (all the UI elements in that Window) are parsed to find the first element of type Table ([ControlType.Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.controltype)).

▶ Of course that Window might host more than one DataGridView: in this case, we can use `FindAll()` instead of `FindFirst()`, then determine which is which using some other condition (the number of Columns, the text of Headers, content of Cells, location, size, parent container etc.).

When the DataGridView of interest is found, we can extract the content of its Cells.
Here comes the second method, `GetDataGridViewRowsCollection()`:

- The first [OrCondition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.orcondition.-ctor) filters out the DataGridView Scrollbars and, possibly, other child Controls of the grid (a customization may include some).
- After, we check whether the DGV has a Header: if it does, the first child Row element name is **`Top Row`**. We can then use the header text to name the Columns of the DataTable that will store the data extracted. Otherwise, just add some default names.
- Then, for each Row element, we enumerate its child elements, representing the Cells. I've added a [NotCondition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.notcondition.-ctor) filter to exclude the Row Header Cell, **`ControlType.Header`**, if any.
- We then iterate the Cell's collection, extract their value using the [GetCurrentPropertyValue()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.getcurrentpropertyvalue) method, setting the Property Type to [ValuePattern.ValueProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.valuepattern.valueproperty), add these values to a List which will provide the `param` array argument of **`DataTable.Rows.Add()`**.

---

```
private DataTable GeDataGridViewDataTable(IntPtr windowHwnd)
{
    var condition = new AndCondition(
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window),
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NativeWindowHandleProperty, windowHwnd.ToInt32())
    );
    var window = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, condition);
    if (window == null) return null;
    var dgv = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, 
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Table));

    if (dgv == null) return null;
    var dt = GetDataGridViewRowsCollection(dgv);
    return dt;
}

private DataTable GetDataGridViewRowsCollection(AutomationElement dgv)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();

    // Skips ScrollBars and other child elements
    var condition = new OrCondition(
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Custom),
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Header)
    );

    var rows = dgv.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, condition).OfType<AutomationElement>().ToList();
    bool hasColumnHeader = (rows[0].Current.Name == "Top Row");

    // First element is the Header (if there's one)
    var dgvHeaderColumns = rows[0].FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);
        
    // Skip the Top/Left header
    for (int i = 1; i < dgvHeaderColumns.Count; i++) {
        dt.Columns.Add(hasColumnHeader ? dgvHeaderColumns[i].Current.Name : "Column"+i);
    }

    // Skips the Row Header, if any
    var notCondition = new NotCondition(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Header));
    foreach (AutomationElement row in rows) {
        var cells = row.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, notCondition);
        var values = new List<object>();
        foreach (AutomationElement cell in cells) {
            values.Add(cell.GetCurrentPropertyValue(ValuePattern.ValueProperty));
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(values.ToArray());
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jimi, I really appreciate it. Do you know if ProcessId of a control will hold the same value across different installations/computers?

Comment: No, of course not. A ProcessID is assigned to an Application when it's first executed. It's always different. The same applies to all handles. To find a Window, you can use `var windows = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window));`. Then inspect each Window element: the `Name` is the Window Title, the FrameworkId can be `Win32`, `WinForms`, `WPF`. So you can filter known details. Or even go down the Window SubTree and check whether has elements you know about (I described this in the notes).

Comment: Note that, from what you're showing now, that is not actually a DataGridView, it's probably a composited Custom Control. You need to *inspect* it to determine how it's built. The Automation methods shown here don't change that much though, you simply need to adapt the filtering conditions to the actual `ControlType` you find there. Automation Properties and Patterns are always the same.

Comment: After so many attempts I would easier to become an astronaut than to work this out. As you can see from the tree that inspect.exe show, there are a bunch of panes, but I can navigate only through the first 2, after those 2 I can't get anything no matter which property I use. What that can be?

Comment: From what I can see there, you don't need to walk all the tree, you just need to find the AutomationElement of type `ControlType.Table`, as shown in the sample here (can you determine its `ClassName`?). That Element has a child named `Data Panel`, which will probably contain the data. Use Inspect to see what child Elements it contains, then parse that collection, using an appropriate filter, if necessary, as shown here. Unless, of course, the data is *painted* on a panel, then you cannot get anything out of it.

Comment: I try almost every possible combination and nothing worked, so I will let it be for the moment, I need to work with other things too. Thank you for your assistance again, I am sure I will use this code again in the future :)